# Get the first row with positive amount in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have data like this

[image]

I want to flag the first positive amount as below

[image]

How do I flag the first positive amount for each id as shown above in Active column?

Answer (score 1):

```
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
('10/01/2022', '1', None),
('18/01/2022', '1', 50),
('31/01/2022', '1', -100)
  ], ['Date', 'Id', 'Amount']
)

from pyspark.sql import Window as W
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = W.partitionBy('Id').orderBy('Date')

df\
    .withColumn('only_pos', F.when(F.col('Amount')>0, F.col('Amount')).otherwise(F.lit(None)))\
    .withColumn('First_pos', F.first('only_pos', True).over(w))\
    .withColumn('Active', F.when(F.col('only_pos')==F.col('First_pos'),F.lit('Yes')).otherwise(F.lit(None)))\
    .select('Date', 'Id', 'Amount', 'Active')\
    .show()
```

```
+----------+---+------+------+
|      Date| Id|Amount|Active|
+----------+---+------+------+
|10/01/2022|  1|  null|  null|
|18/01/2022|  1|    50|   Yes|
|31/01/2022|  1|  -100|  null|
+----------+---+------+------+
```

Comment: You also probably need `orderBy('Date')` for the window function.  It probably is working for this small sample but technically spark dataframe's order is not guaranteed, so it won't safely work without ordering.

Comment: Good point, ```orderBy('Date')``` added!

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot to mention.  Hopefully the column is in datetime type. String of dd/mm/yyyy won't order it in the chronological way.